# Is there anything wrong with this simple circuit ? Transistor + LED

Tags: transistors, led, gpio

This is my first time posting a question.

So this is a simple circuit that I have on a PCB. A 2 in 1 LEDs with a common anode. As soon as I power my PCB both LEDs turn on even if the base isn't pulled up and even when manually pulled down nothing happen. Do you guys have any suggestion for tests to conduct to understand what's wrong ?

LEDs :SM1204BC-R_G
Transistor : NPN Bipolar Transistor 863-MMBT3416LT3G

Thanks,
[image]

Comment: Let's see a photo of your circuit. Your transistors are missing their base resistors so there's a chance that you've blown them and they are short circuit. You're missing the emitter arrow on the transistor on the right.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I was just rushing and forgot to draw it all. I have updated the image.

Comment: I bet the transistors are wired incorrectly. Use the [datasheet](https://datasheet.octopart.com/MMBT3416LT3G-ON-Semiconductor-datasheet-11792177.pdf) and verify.

Comment: Your circuit diagram so far looks good, but the wiring to control base resistors is missing. If you power-up only what is shown (no connections to  base resistors)...both LEDs *should* be off. As others have suggested, a wiring error is likely, or transistors are shorted.

Answer (score 2):

It is not a good idea to use one resistor for both Leds. By this way you will have different brightness when both are activated. Connect the anode directly to +5V and add a resistor between the cathode and the collector of each transistor.

On the other hand, add for each transistor a high value resistor between the base and the ground. It is a bad design to let the base floating.

Comment: Each led is activated at a time, so this should be ok. what could happen with a floating ground ?

Comment: floating base can produce false turn on. by connecting the base to the ground (emitter) through a resistor you can avoid this false turn on. leakage currents and the internal capacitor between the base and the emitter plus the noise can contribute to make a false turn on.